# PorterStemmer: No Stemming Output nor Error while running on Spyder

Tags: python, nltk, spyder, stemming

[As evident in my Spyder's screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3M0R.png) and the below code, I do not get any output nor any error. What am I missing?:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

paragraph = "The Times of India issued its first edition on 3 November 
             1838 as The Bombay Times and Journal of Commerce.[13][14] 
             The paper published Wednesdays and Saturdays under the 
             direction of Raobahadur Narayan Dinanath Velkar, a 
             Maharashtrian Reformist, and contained news from Britain and the world, as well as the Indian Subcontinent. J.E. Brennan was its first editor.[15][16] In 1850, it began to publish 
             daily editions."

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(paragraph)
stemmer = PorterStemmer()

for i in range(len(sentences)):
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentences[i])
    newwords = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in words]
    sentences[i] = ' '.join(newwords)
```

Comment: Did you forget `print` statement?

Comment: In spyder in variable explorer you can see the variable data of your script

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @prashant rana my buttob was click on help instead of variable explorer